# C# application which installs and allows for global command line

Tags: c#, .net, command-prompt

I would like to build a simple .NET application that installs on a windows machine which will allow the end user to open a command prompt and type "google test" which will open google and search for test. But I'm not sure how to install a global "keyword" such as "google". Is this down via Environment variables? How does this link up to my .NET application?

Any advice or pointers is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: The exe has to be named "google" and live somewhere in the PATH variable.  Ask yourself why this is needed though?  How is this any better than using a browser or Cortana?  You have no images in command line, you cant click anything...

Comment: you should install application and include its path in (windows evironment path https://www.howtogeek.com/118594/how-to-edit-your-system-path-for-easy-command-line-access/)

Comment: There is no "global keywords" list for console (command) windows. You run executables  or internal commands (like `dir`). In order to do what you ask, you'd have to write an application named *google* that accepts command line parameters and does the search yourself.

Answer (score 2):

This is beyond a .NET application and belongs into the Area of Setup programms. Visual Studio used to have a Installer Project, but as there are so many 3rd party ways this was removed.

Having "google test" parsed as a google search for "test" is tricky, but possible. However it depends entirely on how the commandline is parsed in a Windows. Wich is pretty much the way it was parsed since DOS 1.0.

If you just enter a word like "google", the commandline will look if there is a Excetuable file (.exe, .com, .bat) of that name in the current folder (working directory). It will then look into all the folders defined in the path variables. However using path variables is so dated, I could find only a single entry in my Windows Path variable now. And it is for MS backward compatibility: "%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;"

Most starting of programms is done via file associations with a specific type. And protocoll associations with a protocoll (like http, https, steam). Indeed my advise would be to make a .NET Programm named "google" whose sole purpose is to to format the proper URL, then send it to console parsing via ProcessStart. And let Windows solve wich programm to use from there.

Edit: And as I only realized after wirting this, apparently Windwos finally supports commandline aliases. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-aliases
Apparently they even added a way to make them via the [WinAPI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/addconsolealias) in Windows 2000. However that requires moving to unmanaged code. And I have no experience, but it appears those aliases might only be valid for one console instance. So you might have to put it into a place like hte autoexec.bat to be called everytime a console is created.

Comment: Seriously? If you open a CMD prompt and type "set PATH" you only have that one entry? You are running a very different set of dev environments than I am, apparently. :) (paths set for php, java, sql server, windows sdk, powershell, nodejs, CUDA, TortoiseXXX, Fiddler, etc. etc.)

Comment: Your third paragraph has answered my question perfectly I think! If I create a .NET application which installs and adds a path variable, and someone opens a command prompt and types "google test" I would want my application to open a browser and search for test. Which I reckon this solves now. Thanks.

Comment: @Paul-Jan: I just looked into the Windows UI for modifying those variables. I also like to install that stuff in a VM. No point having a SQL Server and what not run on my home machine 24/7.

Comment: @user1839601: acutally I just looked and apparently windows nowadays actually has aliases: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-aliases

Comment: @christofer Make sure to look at both the User and System variables in the GUI. Do mind, I don't disagree with the sentiment of your answer at all, it is just that I think (ab)using path variables is a bit more common than your answer suggests.

Comment: @Paul-Jan: You are right, there is a System one with way more entries. The endings being tried are also expanded a bit: ".COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC"

Comment: Is there a better approach that using the Path variables?

Comment: @user1839601: The alias function I mentioend before? The only alternative to a path or alias would be to put a copy of the programm into **every** last Folder (including as new ones are created later). The Alias approach might work, but it is propably still a far cry from aliases in a Unix environment.